# How accurate has to be a description of resources in a triple store with inference disabled?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, sesame, inference, triplestore

Lets say I have an ontology with some classes (:A and :B) and an object property ( :x that that have the domain A and the range B) and I import that ontology into a triple store with no inference mechanism or lets say with inference disabled.

After that if I insert a triple into the triple store like this:

```
<http://instanceOfAClass.com> :x <http://instanceOfBClass.com>
```

For a valid and a correct description of the two instances is it ok to insert only the above triple to state that http://instanceOfAClass.com is of type A and http://instanceOfBClass.com is of type :B, or is it necessary to add the following two triples as well?

```
<http://instanceOfAClass.com> rdf:type :A.
<http://instanceOfBClass.com> rdf:type :B.
```

Comment: Valid and correct with respect to _what_, exactly? A triple store with inferencing disabled will not infer (duh...) the two triples you mention, and they will therefore not appear in query results. But that doesn't mean the query result is invalid or incorrect somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a complete answer - under the assumption that your desired expressivity includes at least domain and range axioms - the two extra axioms are necessary if no inference is enabled.